# Store value in dictionary or retrieve from concatened key

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary that aggregates the same items and sum a specific value from:

```
var test = list.GroupBy(x => new { ID=x.ItemID, Uti=x.UtilityName })
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                             x => x.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.EnergyConsumptionQt)
                            ));
```

This returns a dictionary with a key value that is a concatenation of string ID and string Uti.

I would like to either:

Create a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` in which the key is the combination / concatenation `ItemID+UtilityName` (ID + Uti), or a way to get the values from the test variable above, as the current one I do not know how to specify the value I want from as everything that I try returns: cannot convert 'X' to ''.

Comment: To get a dictionary a GroupBy() needs two parameters : var test = list.GroupBy(x => new { ID=x.ItemID, Uti=x.UtilityName }, y => y)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                             y => y.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.EnergyConsumptionQt)
                            ));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
var test = list.GroupBy(x => new { ID=x.ItemID, Uti=x.UtilityName })
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ID.ToString()+x.Key.Uti, 
                             x => x.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.EnergyConsumptionQt)
                            ));
```

Comment: It worked.... In the end it was simpler than I thought... i was trying to have the Key concatened in first part, which is stupid considering that the Key is set after the `.ToDictionary`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your initial approach is that the annonymous type is a reference type so the dictionary uses the *reference* as a key (rather than the values you want to be combined).

As such if you subsequently try to accesss an element with for example:

```
var elem = test[new {ID=1, Uti="myUtiName"}]
```

then you actually create a NEW object which does not exist in `test` so you would get a `KeyNotFoundException` thrown.

If you use a value type for your dictionary key instead then the dictionary will behave as you are expecting. Perhaps have a `struct` - something like this maybe:

```
struct DictKey
{
    public string UtilityName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then your `test` variable can be initialised with:

```
var test = list
           .GroupBy(x => new DictKey { Id=x.ItemID, UtilityName=x.UtilityName })
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                         x => x.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.EnergyConsumptionQt)));
```

and you can access it's elements with something like:

```
var elem = test[new DictKey{Id=1, UtilityName="myUtiName"}]
```

Comment: Anonymous types are not compared by reference.

Comment: Great explanation. I upvoted due for it. I am keeping as answer the one Marksim because it pointed to using the LINQ to maintain the simple structure of the dictionary <Key, Value>. Nonetheless, you provided a different way ro address the issue that maybe could prove useful in the future and added to my knowledge. And for all that I am very grateful.